# I'm following the learn-rails tutorial book 2 from http://learn-rails.com/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am a beginner!

I keep getting this error in Terminal when I start rails server:

```
rails server localhost:3000

Exiting
/Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/localhost:3000 (LoadError)
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `try_require'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in `print_boot_information'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michael/Projects/RailsApps/learn-rails/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/michael/Projects/RailsApps/learn-rails/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michael/Projects/RailsApps/learn-rails/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /Users/michael/Projects/RailsApps/learn-rails/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I'm on a 2013 MacBook Air running OSX EL Cap 10.11.6
    rvm 1.27.0
    ruby 2.3.1
    rails 4.2.5
I am running rails server from Projects/RailsApps/learn-rails. I am working through chapter 10 Configure and had set my environmental variables in .bashrc and configured the config/secrets.yml file to pull from the environmental variables. 
    I have tried googling for help but could not find any answers that pertain. 
    I also could not find an answer on SO or Quora that could help me out.

**UPDATE
    This is the error message I receive after running 'bundle' and 'rails g simple_form:install'

```
Michaels-MacBook-Air:learn-rails michael$ rails g simple_form:install
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration.
/Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval': (erb):15: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input
;  =ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] ; _e...
    ^ (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `secrets'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:178:in `key_generator'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:206:in `message_verifier'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/globalid-0.3.7/lib/global_id/railtie.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/michael/Projects/RailsApps/learn-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I have checked my gemfile. `gem simple_form` is listed and uncommented from gemfile.

Comment: now I am getting this error after rebooting the whole machine. [Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration. I have tried 'rails generate simple_form:install' and still get a long printout of errors telling me that something is wrong with my system.

Comment: What command did you actually use to start the rails server?

Comment: @ArunKumar rails server.

Comment: Can you try running `bundle` and then `rails s`?

Comment: Same error msg. This is so frustrating. I just want to learn...

Comment: let me clarify. 'bundle' worked. I have 19 gemfile dependencies and 65 gems installed

Comment: You are able to start the rails server right?

Comment: These are the first few lines of the error i get when i run 'rails s'                                  Michaels-MacBook-Air:learn-rails michael$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration.
Exiting
/Users/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `
    ^

Comment: The whole error msg is really long 6k+ characters

Comment: Try running `rails g simple_form:install` and see if its working. If not, please update your question with the error message.

Comment: Can you post your `secrets.yml` file?

Comment: `.bashrc` is for your terminal, for global system dev settings, not project. I dont know about OSX, since I use linux but you set your env variables in the config directory. Can you please edit and elaborate what exactly were you doing/following?

Comment: The instructions stated to set up global system dev settings and pass it to the config/secrets.yml file. ex: 'MAILCHIMP_API_KEY: <% =ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>'. this is done after setting it up in .bashrc with 'export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY="your mailchimp api key"'. Since screwing around in .bashrc, I can not use 'rails server' or 'rails s'. I'm thinking about reinstalling the whole system and going at it again.

Comment: @RenaissanceRogue If you're still stuck at that issue, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your `secrets.yml` file, you have something like this.

```
<% =ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>
```

`=ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]` is not a valid `ruby` expression and thats why you're getting the error.

It should actually be

```
<%= ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Hope this helps!